# Why doesn't Green Arrow just ask Flash to capture Damien Darhk?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

In *The Flash* episode "Legends of Today" (Season 2, Episode 8), Team Arrow is not doing well in their fight with Damien Darhk and his Ghosts when Barry Allen comes in and speeds them out. Damien Darhk is quite surprised by this development, and didn't seem to have any way to react to Flash.

Why doesn't Arrow just ask Flash to capture Damien Darhk? Sure, they may not understand his magic, but surely Flash could speed in, inject him with a tranquilizer, and then carry his unconscious body to Oliver and the team. (Heck, he could even give John Constantine a call and ask him to put a binding spell or something on Darhk before he wakes up).

So why doesn't Arrow just ask Flash to capture Damien Darhk?

<sub>And yes, I'm fully aware that the out-of-universe reason is that there wouldn't be a villain for Season 4 if this happened.</sub>

Comment: shh, dont ask about obvious plot holes

Comment: Technically, with the exception of when the Flash is on Earth-2, Flash could just work with Felicity and fight crime in both cities. With the abilities they've given him, that's definitely a possibility. But that would invalidate the premise of having an Arrow show any longer. We're in the "Can't Batman retire because Superman exists?" category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off if the Flash  solve all of arrows problems then they have to change the name of the show from the arrow to the Flash. Secondly as we saw in the first arrow and Flash crossover Oliver prefers to do things his way without the Flash who doesn't have Oliver's training. While Things have changed since that season and Oliver and Barry are more used to working together there probably is some frictions between them when it comes working together. Thirdly we have no way of knowing that a tranquilizer would even work on Damien Dark. 
Personally with his ability to teleport and his ability of telekinesis and whatever other unknown abilities he has.  plus hundreds of years of training and experience, I think Damien Dark would easily defeat the Flash.

Comment: Also, dark's powers appear to be magical, not metahuman. From what I've seen in the Flash TV series (not read the comics), magic probably isn't Flashes forte. Sure, one could assume the Flash could rush in and steal the totem... but if it is protected by magic, that's a whole other story.